# React Native Android Text Component extra padding

Tags: react-native, zeplin

I was wondering why am getting these weird `padding` on my Text in react-native. I tried every thing to just get a perfect text but nothing seems to work the only thing that worked was `paddingVertical` and `paddingHorizontal` but it's way too hacky and not reliable.

```
<Text numberOfLines={1} 
      style={{
            backgroundColor: 'red', 
            lineHeight: 92, 
            textAlign: 'center', 
            textAlignVertical: 'center', 
            padding: 0, 
            margin: 0, 
            fontSize: 92,  
            color: '#2d76ff', 
            fontFamily: 'Roboto-Regular', 
            includeFontPadding: false}}>
      {this.state.documents}
</Text>
```

**Zeplin**

[image]

**Screenshot from my HTC**

[image]

Comment: Can you update your question to add a bit more information? Where exactly is the extra padding you are trying to remove in your screenshot?

Comment: Are you using a custom font (I don't think Roboto is default)? Is this behavior specific to either Android or iOS? I had a similar problem on Android where I found a kind of hacky solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41570343

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I stumbled onto this issue because I was experiencing the same. The text component has a prop called `includeFontPadding`. You can set it to false to remove the extra padding.

Check the React Native Docs for reference: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text-style-props#includefontpadding

Comment: I had no idea this was a thing - this will save me a ton of headaches in future. Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Try adding this to style

```
includeFontPadding:false
```

Comment: I am not sure why this isn't a default style.

Comment: Agreed — Spent hours trying to figure out why fonts aligned perfectly on iOS and not Android.

Comment: Perfect Solution!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Additional: Every add or remove includeFontPadding property, should refresh(press r) on metro server(in my case react native 0.66 and use own font family)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please make sure your answer is easy to read and understand and that it is directly related to the question.