# React Native: Custom font renders differently on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, fonts, react-native

In the picture below I have inspected the same Text-component as rendered on Android on the left and iOS on the right. It seems that iOS renders the font in top of the Text-container.

I'm using the same TTF font-file for both Android and iOS. (I found an online reference to the font I'm using [here](https://github.com/zolitariuz/ceuhz/blob/master/fonts/Metric-Regular.ttf).)

Any ideas how to make the font render the same for both Android and iOS?

[image]

Just to be clear, the difference is not caused by any styling (margin, font size, etc.). It's exactly the same.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a fix but it doesn't feel right. I think you should find another font that renders the same on each device.

You can play around with the `lineHeight`, `padding` and `margin` to get the same vertical alignment for your text components :

**Ios:**

```
instructions: {
    fontFamily: 'Metric-Regular',
    fontSize: 50,
    lineHeight: 50,
    paddingTop: 25,
    marginBottom: -35,
    marginTop: 35
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me to find a solution!! Because I need to support multiline Texts I can't set height, like you did. However, it seems to work when I add a padding at the top and a negative margin at the bottom of the Text component, both values relative to the font size.

Comment: @henkimon Thanks, I'm glad I helped. As you can see, I improved my answer based on your comment. If you could accept it, that would mean the world to me.

Answer (score 8):

Problem is with `lineGap` and `ascender` `.ttf` font file parameters. Fix them using `ftxdumperfuser` tool. Check https://medium.com/@martin_adamko/consistent-font-line-height-rendering-42068cc2957d